# How to toggle comment on a line matching a pattern?

Tags: python, django, awk, sed, makefile

I'm working on a Django project where I've created a *makefile* task to reset my database setup (*i.e.* `reset-db`).

However, as I just want to `syncdb` the *core* application, I need to be able to toggle comment on the *legacy* app line. Commenting prior to the `syncdb` and uncommenting after (so other operation happen normally).

#### Default state

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    …
    'django_extensions',
    'core',
    'legacy' # @reset-db
)
```

#### Goal state

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    …
    'django_extensions',
    'core',
    # 'legacy' # @reset-db
)
```

### Makefile `reset-db`

The task is currently

```
reset-db:
    # cmd to comment line
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${SETTINGS} sudo -u postgres -H dropdb evrpa \
    && sudo -u postgres -H createdb evrpa -O elopez; \
    ./manage.py syncdb --noinput --database=default;
    # cmd to UNcomment line
```

So what's the `sed` or `awk` command to do that?

Comment: This is a pointless thing to do. `syncdb` takes an app name as an optional parameter.

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you link to a reference, I don't see anything like that in the [`1.6` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#syncdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a copy of the original file, modify it, use it, then restore it:

```
mv ${SETTINGS_PY} ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp &&
sed '/@reset-db/s/^/#/' ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp > ${SETTINGS_PY} &&
./manage.py syncdb --noinput --database=default &&
mv ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp ${SETTINGS_PY}
```

That way you don't have to come up with a script to try to get the modified file back to it's original content since you have a copy of that original file to restore from.

I assume you have a good reason for not quoting your variables and so I have also left them unquoted.

I added `&&` at the end of every line because you always want to test for the previous command succeeding before executing the next command. If that's not the right syntax to do that in your makefile, change it as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've done it

### Commenting

```
awk '/@reset-db/{ $0="# " $0 } {print}' ${SETTINGS_PY} > ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp
```

1. For lines matching the pattern `/@reset-db/`, I updated the line content by prefixing `#` to it using `{ $0="# " $0 }`.
2. Then I print all lines with `{print}`.

### Uncommenting

```
awk '/^# .*@reset-db/{ $0=gensub(/^#(.*)/, "\\1", "", $0) } {print}' ${SETTINGS_PY} > ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp
```

1. For lines matching the pattern `/^# .*@reset-db/`, I updated the current line content by removing `#` using `{ $0=gensub(/^#(.*)/, "\\1", "", $0) }`.
2. Then I print all lines with `{print}`.

### Full task

**Note:** You need to escape the `$` in *makefile* scripts with another `$` (*e.g.* `$0` → `$$0`).

```
reset-db:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${SETTINGS} sudo -u postgres -H dropdb evrpa \
    && sudo -u postgres -H createdb evrpa -O elopez; \
    awk '/@reset-db/{ $$0="# " $$0 } {print}' ${SETTINGS_PY} > ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp \
        && mv ${SETTINGS_PY}{.tmp,}
    ./manage.py syncdb --noinput --database=default;
    awk '/^# .*@reset-db/{ $$0=gensub(/^#(.*)/, "\\1", "", $$0) } {print}' ${SETTINGS_PY} > ${SETTINGS_PY}.tmp \
        && mv ${SETTINGS_PY}{.tmp,}
```